# How to use Playwright to interact with Metamask?

Tags: python, playwright, metamask

I'd like to automate interactions with Metamask using Playwright and Python, but I don't understand exactly how the extension is controlled. When I open the browser the extension may or may not be configured. Each time the extension is requested, it opens a new page in the handler array.

How do I master the extension, load correctly, configure networks, open at the right time, know which handler is correct, approve or reject transactions and everything else?

Any full tutorial? Course? Book?

Answer (score 3):

There is a great tool (e2e testing framework) for automating metamask (using playwright or cypress, what ever you prefer) which I'm using - it's called **[synpress](https://github.com/Synthetixio/synpress)**

It seems to be very well maintained past few years and is being continuously developed.

They have great repositories with examples for setup:
[github.com/drptbl/synpress-examples](https://github.com/drptbl/synpress-examples)

and CI:
[github.com/Synthetixio/synpress/tree/dev/.github/workflows](https://github.com/Synthetixio/synpress/tree/dev/.github/workflows)

Sadly, it's not written in *Python*, but *JavaScript* (also supports *TypeScript*).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Have you managed to work with Synpress? I tried the isolated state example , but with no luck. It starts fine, but cannot get past the sign of the request in the Metamask Notification window :/

Answer (score -1):

You can not interact with extensions in playwright. You could script windows tasks like clicking, waiting, pressing keys etc and run it with headfull browser mode.